# SmartTable Draggable columns

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, smart-table

I am looking for a way to make draggable columns within SmartTable.  I basically need to reorder entire columns in my table.  I came across lrDragNDrop, however I found it doesn't work in FireFox.  I need something that supports both Chrome and Firefox. 
I also looked into ui-sortable, but it seems like it can't be applied to tables, only lists.

Can anyone suggest a solution with a simple example of how to implement it on a table?

Thanks!